# Linking push-forward of measures and the Legendre transform

Tags: convex-analysis, pushforward, legendre-transformation

Suppose that $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are absolutely continuous w.r.t Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, for which the second moment of both measures are finite. By Brenier's theorem, there exists a convex function $\phi$ such that $\nabla \phi_{\#} \rho_1 = \rho_2$, or equivalently, $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g\, \mathrm{d}\rho_2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(\nabla \phi)\, \mathrm{d}\rho_1.$$ I found in a paper that we also have $$\nabla \phi^*_{\#} \rho_2 = \rho_1,\tag{*}$$ in which $\phi^*$ is the Legendre transform (or convex dual) of $\phi$, defined by $$\phi^*(q) = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \{q\cdot x - \phi(q)\}.$$ May I know how can we justify (*)? Thank you very much!

Comment: This might sound dumb but isn't this explained in the paper? If not, can't you look at the bibliography of said paper?

Comment: @Saegusa Thanks for your question, this is not explained in the paper, and there is not reference for this specific fact that is mentioned in the paper...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this basically follows from $(\nabla \phi)^{-1} = \nabla \phi^*$ which holds if both, $\phi$ and $\phi^*$ are differentiable. This formula can also be extended to the non-differentiable case via
$x^* \in \partial \phi(x)$ if and only if $x \in \partial \phi(x^*)$, where "$\partial$" denotes the subdifferential.

Suppose that $\phi$ and $\phi^*$ are differentiable.
We have
$\rho_2(A) = \rho_1(\nabla \phi^{-1}(A))$
for all measurable sets $A$.
If we plug in
$A = (\nabla\phi^*)^{-1}(B)$,
we get
$\rho_2((\nabla\phi^*)^{-1}(B)) = \rho_1(B)$
due to
$\nabla \phi^{-1}((\nabla\phi^*)^{-1}(B)) = B$.

In the general case, it might be possible to use the fact that $\phi$ and $\phi^*$ are a.e. differentiable
(together with the absolute continuity of the measures).

Comment: Can you explain how the stated identity implies the new push-forward relation (i.e., $\nabla \phi^*_{\#} \rho_2 = \rho_1$)?